# Multiword Synonyms and Phrase Queries

Tags: elasticsearch

Is there a mistake in the Elastic documentation?

Given the following index mapping:

```
PUT /my_index
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "filter": {
        "my_synonym_filter": {
          "type": "synonym",
          "synonyms": [
            "usa,united states,u s a,united states of america"
          ]
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "my_synonyms": {
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "my_synonym_filter"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Given this document:

```
put /my_index/country/1
{
  "title" : "The United States is wealthy"
}
```

In the documentation it states:

These phrases would not match:

The usa is wealthy

The united states of america is wealthy

The U.S.A. is wealthy

However, these phrases would:

United states is wealthy

Usa states of wealthy

The U.S. of wealthy

U.S. is america

However this does not seem to be the case -  the phrases that should match aren't matching at all! Here is the query I am running (without synonym expansion at query time as per the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/multi-word-synonyms.html)):

```
GET /my_index/country/_search
{

    "query" : {
        "match_phrase" : {
            "title" : {
               "query" : "United States is wealthy",
               "analyzer": "standard"
            }

        }
    }
}
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example in documentation works for me.

Probably you forgot to set the analyzer for `title` field in the mapping.

Example:

1) Create Index

```
PUT /my_index
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "filter": {
        "my_synonym_filter": {
          "type": "synonym",
          "synonyms": [
            "usa,united states,u s a,united states of america"
          ]
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "my_synonyms": {
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "my_synonym_filter"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

2) Add Mapping

```
PUT my_index/country/_mapping
{
    "properties" : {
        "title" : {"type" : "string","analyzer" : "my_synonyms"}
    }
}
```

3) Index Document

```
PUT /my_index/country/1
{
  "title" : "The United States is wealthy"
}
```

4) Query

```
GET /my_index/country/_search
{

    "query" : {
        "match_phrase" : {
            "title" : {
               "query" : "United States is wealthy",
               "analyzer": "standard"
            }

        }
    }
}
```

5) Response :

```
{
   "took": 8,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 5,
      "successful": 5,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 1,
      "max_score": 0.75942194,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "my_index",
            "_type": "country",
            "_id": "1",
            "_score": 0.75942194,
            "_source": {
               "title": "The United States is wealthy"
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Comment: Try changing the query text to "usa is wealthy", I think you will end up with no results because your query match query is using the wrong analyzer

Comment: @IanGabes true no doubt :) but I think the question in OP is specific to example in [definitive guide](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/multi-word-synonyms.html) the use case without using synonym expansion at query time

Comment: @keety That's correct my question was in regard to not using synonym expansion at query time. Thanks

Comment: @Keety I've just noticed that "The U.S. of wealthy" and "U.S. is america" should work according to the docs but they don't.

Comment: @ImranAzad good catch  it makes sense why it does not match `GET /my_index/_analyze?analyzer=standard&text=U.S. of wealthy`  returns `U.S` as a token which is not one of the indexed terms on the other hand if you use `U S of wealthy` this would match.The example is kind of vague on the analyzer used during search but `standard` would be a good assumption.  You probably should file an issue [here](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-definitive-guide/issues)

Comment: @Keety many thanks for preserving my sanity, I thought perhaps I was losing it!

Answer (score 1):

So close, you missed one thing!

In your query, you should change the analyzer! You have to run your query text against the `my_synonym` analyzer to be able to match the synonyms. Currently, you have the query using the `standard` analyzer, which simply tokenizes your text as `united`, `states`,`is`,`wealthy`, instead of also using all of your synonyms.

Change this:

```
GET /my_index/country/_search
{

    "query" : {
        "match_phrase" : {
            "title" : {
               "query" : "United States is wealthy",
               "analyzer": "standard"
            }

        }
    }
}
```

To this:

```
GET /my_index/country/_search
{

    "query" : {
        "match_phrase" : {
            "title" : {
               "query" : "United States is wealthy",
               "analyzer": "my_synonyms"
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Now, when you query, the text `United States` will properly get tokenized to `usa`